# Keeping alive Docker containers with supervisord

Tags: docker, supervisord, systemd

I end my Debian Dockerfile with these lines:

```
EXPOSE 80 22

COPY etc/supervisor/conf.d /etc/supervisor/conf.d
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

In `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/start.conf` file:

```
[program:ssh]
command=/usr/sbin/service ssh restart

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon off;'

[program:systemctl]
command=/bin/systemctl daemon-reload

[program:systemctl]
command=/bin/systemctl start php7-fpm.service
```

If I try to run this Docker image with the following command:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:80 -p 8081:22 lanti/debian
```

It's immediately stops running. if I try to run it on the foreground:

```
$ docker run -it -v /home/core/share:/root/share -p 8080:80 -p 8081:22 lanti/debian
```

It's the same, immediate exit. If I run with bash CMD:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v /home/core/share:/root/share -p 8080:80 -p 8081:22 lanti/debian bash
```

It stays active in the console, but the predefined commands by supervisor not run, so I need to run `$ service supervisor restart` inside the container, otherwise Nginx and SSH won't be started.

How I can start a docker container with multiple commands run at startup? In the past I used `ExecStartPost` lines in a systemd file under the host OS, but becouse of that, the systemd file became complex so I try to move the pre-start commands into the container, to run automatically at any type of startup.

This docker container will have nginx, php, ssh, phpmyadmin and mysql in the future. I don't want multiple containers.

Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Lets preface this by saying running the kitchen sink in a docker container is not a best practice.   Docker is not a virtual machine.

That said, a few problems.

- just like the processes that supervisor controls, supervisor itself should NOT daemonize.   Add -n
- I'm not entirely sure why you expect, need, or want to have systemd and supervisor running.   Most docker containers do not have a functioning init system.   Why not just user supervisor for everything?   Unless docker has significantly changed in the last couple versions,  systemd inside the container will not work like you think it should.

Comment: Canonical way to use Docker is 1 process per container. You can easily do that with docker-compose @lanti

Comment: I see. So I can connect let's say a PHP+Nginx container with a MySQL container? Is it a good idea to keep nginx + php in the same container? I dropped the systemd from the supervisor. I followed a tutorial which wasn't for docker. Now supervisor starting the php-fpm also.